# Calculating percentage in a pig query by group

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table with three columns (typeofcrime, disctrict, year)

Example:

```
typeofcrime district year
HOMICIDE 092 2016
THEFT 053 2017
HOMICIDE 075 2016
ASSAULT 025 2014
```

I want to calculate the percentage of **HOMICIDES** for each district and year.

Something like this:

```
DISTRICT YEAR PERCENTAGE OF HOMICDE
075  2016   33%
092  2016    0%
025 2014     2%
```

How can I do this in PigLatin?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a table (`A`) where each row represents one crime incident and you want to calculate the percent of homicides in each district and year out of all crimes for that district and year, right?

You can do this with a nested foreach statement:

```
B = GROUP A BY (district, year);
C = FOREACH B {
    homicides = FILTER A BY typeofcrime == 'HOMICIDE';
    GENERATE 
        FLATTEN(group) AS (district, year),
        (float)COUNT(homicides)/(float)COUNT(A) AS homicidepercent;
};
```